# Primary key integrity constraint violation with Hibernate and HSQLDB

Tags: java, hibernate, hsqldb

Good morning everyone

I am using HSQLDB with Hibernate. I have a situation where even if I set the primary key value, I am still getting an `integrity constraint violation: NOT NULL check constraint; SYS_CT_10346 table: NUMBERS column: PK`. As can be seen below.

```
SEVERE: integrity constraint violation: NOT NULL check constraint; SYS_CT_10346 table: NUMBERS column: PK
org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not insert: [entity.Numbers]
    at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:71)
    at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:43)
    at org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.performInsert(AbstractReturningDelegate.java:40)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2158)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2638)
    at org.hibernate.action.EntityIdentityInsertAction.execute(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:48)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:250)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:298)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:181)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:107)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:187)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:33)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:172)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:27)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:70)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.fireSave(SessionImpl.java:535)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:523)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:519)
    at dbconn.NumbersDB.saveNumbers(NumbersDB.java:75)
    at gui.UI.saveNumberStateButtonActionPerformed(UI.java:1807)
    at gui.UI.access$1800(UI.java:39)
    at gui.UI$20.actionPerformed(UI.java:788)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6505)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6270)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4861)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:729)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:688)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:686)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:702)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:700)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:699)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: integrity constraint violation: NOT NULL check constraint; SYS_CT_10346 table: NUMBERS column: PK
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.Util.sqlException(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.Util.sqlException(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCPreparedStatement.fetchResult(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(Unknown Source)
    at org.hibernate.id.IdentityGenerator$GetGeneratedKeysDelegate.executeAndExtract(IdentityGenerator.java:73)
    at org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.performInsert(AbstractReturningDelegate.java:33)
    ... 55 more
```

Here is my mapping

```
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<!-- Generated 22 Feb 2016 9:01:34 PM by Hibernate Tools 3.2.1.GA -->
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="entity.Numbers" table="NUMBERS" schema="PUBLIC" catalog="PUBLIC">
        <id name="pk" type="int">
            <column name="PK" />
            <generator class="native" />
        </id>
        <many-to-one name="account" class="entity.Account" fetch="select">
            <column name="ALLOCATEDACCOUNT"/>
        </many-to-one>
        <property name="number" type="string">
            <column name="NUMBER" length="25" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <property name="allocated" type="boolean">
            <column name="ALLOCATED" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <property name="alias" type="string">
            <column name="ALIAS" length="25" />
        </property>
        <property name="geographic" type="java.lang.Boolean">
            <column name="GEOGRAPHIC" />
        </property>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

And my entity class

```
package entity;
// Generated 21 Feb 2016 1:44:55 AM by Hibernate Tools 3.2.1.GA

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;

/**
 * Numbers generated by hbm2java
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "NUMBERS", schema = "PUBLIC", catalog = "PUBLIC")
public class Numbers implements java.io.Serializable {

    private Integer pk;
    private String number;
    private Account account;
    private boolean allocated;
    private String alias;
    private Boolean geographic;

    public Numbers() {
    }

    public Numbers(Integer pk, String number, boolean allocated) {
        this.pk = pk;
        this.number = number;
        this.allocated = allocated;
    }

    public Numbers(Integer pk, Account account, String number, boolean allocated, String alias, Boolean geographic) {
        this.pk = pk;
        this.account = account;
        this.number = number;
        this.allocated = allocated;
        this.alias = alias;
        this.geographic = geographic;
    }

    @Id
    @Column(name = "PK", unique = true, nullable = false)    
    public Integer getPk() {
        return this.pk;
    }

    public void setPk(Integer pk) {
        this.pk = pk;
    }

    @Column(name = "NUMBER", nullable = false, length = 25)
    public String getNumber() {
        return this.number;
    }

    public void setNumber(String number) {
        this.number = number;
    }

    @Column(name = "ALLOCATED", nullable = false)
    public boolean isAllocated() {
        return this.allocated;
    }

    public void setAllocated(boolean allocated) {
        this.allocated = allocated;
    }

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "ALLOCATEDACCOUNT")
    public Account getAccount() {
        return this.account;
    }

    public void setAccount(Account account) {
        this.account = account;
    }

    @Column(name = "ALIAS", length = 25)
    public String getAlias() {
        return this.alias;
    }

    public void setAlias(String alias) {
        this.alias = alias;
    }

    @Column(name = "GEOGRAPHIC")
    public Boolean getGeographic() {
        return this.geographic;
    }

    public void setGeographic(Boolean geographic) {
        this.geographic = geographic;
    }
}
```

and lastly the code that I am trying to execute

```
public boolean saveNumbers(Set numbersSet) {
        try {
            Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
            session.beginTransaction();
            for (Iterator<Numbers> it = numbersSet.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
                Numbers numbers = it.next();
                if (numbers.getPk() == null) {
                    numbers.setPk(new Integer(5));
                    session.save(numbers);
                } else {
                    numbers = (Numbers) session.merge(numbers);
                    session.saveOrUpdate(numbers);
                }
            }
            session.getTransaction().commit();
            return true;
        } catch (HibernateException he) {
            he.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
    }
```

The exception is getting thrown by `session.save(numbers);`

Even when I set the primary key manually, as seen in the above sample it still throwing an exception.
I have tried to set the annotations as seen below but this still gives me the same exception.

```
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "PK", unique = true, nullable = false)
```

your assistance would be greatly appreciated

Thank you

Comment: Don't use unnecessary properties `@Column(name = "PK", unique = true, nullable = false)` —  `@Id` means that it is unique! I am not sure about `nullable = false`, but with a _generated value_ you don't need it too.

Comment: thank you for the suggestion but even if a take out the unique = true it is still  throwing the same exception

Comment: You are welcome. It doesn't fix an error, of course. It was just an advice.

Comment: And you don't need it too `@Basic(optional = false)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Good Morning All

So after much pain and suffering the answer to the issue was as follows, when creating your tables don't forget to set the primary key to IDENTITY. Thank you everyone for your thoughts.

Regards

Brian

Answer (score 0):

You're assigning the same PK 5 to all entities without already assigned PK. That means, that you try to save all new instances with exactly the same PK value.

If you're using generated ID, don't assign anything to your PK field of the entity.

Comment: Hi There Thank you for taking the time to answer. I put it in to demonstrate that even if a statically set it once, on an empty table it still throws an exception. The issue is that even if I take it out I get that sane issue

Comment: Then set PK field as nullable. The exception talks about not null check not passed. Where did you get the nullable=false at your PK field in Numbers? It says generated from hbm.xml, but didn't you alter it? Also check which takes precedence whether hbm.xml or annotations.

Comment: Thank you again. I got the nullable = false when I generated the XML. The entity code seen is as generated, I have been trying to alter it to get it to work. All My other entity classes have the same annotations so I'm really frustrated by this one. How can I determine hat takes precedence?

Comment: Try search documentation for your version. But I still see inconsistency between hbm.XML and your annotations. You don't have any generated ID specification in your annotations. I would advise to use either hbm.XML or annotations only to start with. How do you configure hibernate?